# webpage refresh the coding in controller function is not reflected in laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

In Laravel controller function the coding has make changes and save it,when I  refresh the webpage the coding is not reflected?

Actually code:-

```
public function generate(Request $request) 
{ # Validate Data $request->validate
([ 'reset_mailid' => 'required|exists:vs360_tables,mailid' ]);
# Generate An OTP
    // Create a new instance of the Request class
    $request = $request->input('reset_mailid');
    
    // Call the generateOtp() method with the correct argument type

    $verificationCode = $this->generateOtp($request);

    $message = "Your OTP To Login is :- ".$verificationCode->otp;
    # Return With OTP 

     return redirect()->route('otp.verification', ['reset_mailid' => $verificationCode->reset_mailid])->with('success',  $message); 
}

public function generateOtp(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('mailid', $request)->first();

    # User Does not Have Any Existing OTP
    $verificationCode = VerificationCode::where('reset_mailid', $user->reset_mailid)->latest()->first();

    $now = Carbon::now();

    if($verificationCode && $now->isBefore($verificationCode->expire_at)){
        return $verificationCode;
    }

    // Create a New OTP
    return VerificationCode::create([
        'reset_mailid' => $request->input('reset_mailid'),
        'otp' => rand(123456, 999999),
        'expire_at' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10)
    ]);
}
```

```
App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthOtpController::generateOtp(): Argument #1 ($request) must be of type Illuminate\\Http\\Request, string given, called in D:\\localserver\\htdocs\\Laravel_Projects\\final_vserve360\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthOtpController.php on line 32
```

Comment: You have a problem in your generate method, what your are doing actually is replacing the laravel request object inot reset_mailid, so the request variable has a string now, change your code like this:

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your generate method, what your are doing actually is replacing the laravel request object inot reset_mailid, so the request variable has a string now, change your code like this:

```
$request_mail_id = $request->input('reset_mailid');
// in the avobe line you have to change the variable name into something 
// else rather then request 

// Call the generateOtp() method with the correct argument type
// now pass the new variable into your function

$verificationCode = $this->generateOtp($request_mail_id);
```

In the second function you dont need http request, just receive the parameter in any name, change the code like below:

```
public function generateOtp($mail_id)
{
    $user = User::where('mailid', $mail_id)->first();

    # User Does not Have Any Existing OTP
    $verificationCode = VerificationCode::where('reset_mailid', $user- 
    >reset_mailid)->latest()->first();

    $now = Carbon::now();

    if($verificationCode && $now->isBefore($verificationCode->expire_at)){
        return $verificationCode;
    } 

    // Create a New OTP
    return VerificationCode::create([
        'reset_mailid' => $request->input('reset_mailid'),
        'otp' => rand(123456, 999999),
        'expire_at' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10)
    ]);
}
```

IT should work now

Comment: When i make code changes in controller function the code is not reflected in webpage when we refresh

Answer (score 0):

i change the code in controller function as you say but the coding is not reflected in webpage when i refresh?

```
{

    # Validate Data

    $request->validate([

        'reset_mailid' => 'required|exists:vs360_tables,mailid'

    ]);



    # Generate An OTP

    $verificationCode = $this->generateOtp($request->reset_mailid);



    $message = "Your OTP To Login is - ".$verificationCode->otp;

    # Return With OTP



    return redirect()->route('otp.verification', ['reset_mailid' => $verificationCode->reset_mailid])->with('success',  $message);

}



public function generateOtp(Request $request)

{

    $reset_mailid = $request->reset_mailid;

    $user = User::where('mailid', $reset_mailid)->first();

    // dd('$reset_mailid');

    # User Does not Have Any Existing OTP

    // $verificationCode = VerificationCode::where('reset_mailid', $user->reset_mailid)->latest()->first();



    // $now = Carbon::now();



    // if($verificationCode && $now->isBefore($verificationCode->expire_at)){

    //     return $verificationCode;
```

Comment: double check if your route returns to the method of your controller

Comment: Thank you i got the result @MuhammadSajidulIslam